# Proper positioning for z-index and opacity

Tags: html, css

I have nested link in two absolute div's like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftPostHolder">
        <div class="leftPost">
            <h3><a href="#">link</a></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

First div(leftPostHolder) has black background, second one(leftPost) has red and when second div is hovered opacity of it is set to 0.5 and link background is set to white. Now I want that link to be above these two div's so that darken effect is not applied to it but just to second div with red background. Link with it's background should not be overlayed with that darken effect with opacity.
How to set link above those two elements? I tried with z-index and positioning that link but without success.
Full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/v21t290a/

Comment: So on mousehover the back ground become red, with link on top of it ? is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Dreamweaver on hover opacity is set to 0.5 over second div and link also. I want it only over second div so link is displayed clearly without that overlay coming from opacity

Comment: After removing the opacity from second div displays the link clearly. As the a is children so it inherites from parent. We can place it out side with position absolute, abd with use of jquery it place it on top of the div.

Comment: @Dreamweaver yes I know, but I hoped there is a quick workaround just in css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a `z-index` issue.
Your `a`-tag is a child of `leftPost` which means it will inherit the opacity. Changing the Z-index will not change this.

The solution to your issue would be to either move the `a`-element so it's not a direct child of `leftPost`

**or**

Put the Opacity on an element that is not the parent of your link.

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
$(".leftPost").hover(function() {
  $(".leftPost a").toggleClass("aHover");
});
```

```css
.container {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  -ms-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.leftPostHolder {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.leftPost {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  display: table;
  z-index: 2;
}

.leftPost:hover{
    
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  -mos-transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform-origin: top center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -mos-transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
}

.opacityDiv {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  display: table;
  z-index: 1;
}
.leftPost:hover + .opacityDiv {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.leftPost h3 {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.leftPost a{
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
}
.aHover {
  color: #454545!important;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftPostHolder">
    <div class="leftPost">
      <h3><a href="#">link</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="opacityDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```